# Set Button Right & Center Bootstrap Alert Box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set bootstrap button right and center in an alert box. The button pulls to the right but it doesn't center. Here is my Bootply: https://www.bootply.com/ORxGVJq0kG#

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in text-center" role="alert"><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong>Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="finish()" type="button">Finish</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding "text-center" class to the button and add this to the alert:
`style="line-height: 34px;"` because the button has a height of 34px, which means the container has to have a line-height of 34px as well.

Comment: you can make it as the selected answer then ;)